# Alarm does not make itself visible

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

In monodroid I want to set an alarm. I would like to have a function I can pass a `seconds` to and the function creates the alarm at the `current time + seconds`.

All examples I found were nested in some other projects. I am looking for a general purpose solution.

I found

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(alarm);

Intent i= new Intent("MY_INTENT");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

and changed it to

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService);
Intent i = new Intent("MY_INTENT");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
seconds = Convert.ToInt16(txtMinutes.Text) * 60;
am.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup,SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + (seconds * 1000), pi);
```

But after `seconds` passed, literally nothing happens.

What to change?

Comment: Are you just using `MY_INTENT` or is it an actual intent?

Comment: @Cheesebaron For my purpose - setting an alarm as in the clock-app - what should `MY_INTENT` look like instead?

Comment: It should be the actual `Activity` you want to launch.